# Rails: How can I count the total number of contacts a user has when "Contact" is polymorphic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, rails-models

I have a model called `Contacts` which is associated with other models through `Contactable`.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
  validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank'}
```

"Leadhooks" is one of the models "Contacts" is associated with using contactable.

```
class Leadhook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
```

Here is my user model...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leadhooks
  has_many :contacts, through: :contactable
```

In the analytics page of my app, I would like to display the total count of all the contacts a user has.

However, since contacts aren't directly associated to the user and are associated through the other models as `contactable`, when I tried `@user.contacts.all`, I got this error...

**ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError at / Could not find the association :contactable in model User**

How can I count the total number of contacts a user has when each `Contact` is associated through another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear.

If you simply want to be able to run `user.contacts`, then you need to add this to your `User` model:

```
has_many :contacts
```

However, if you want the count of all `contactables` of a `user` that are connected to it via its `contacts`, then you need to add the following to your `User` model:

```
has_many :contactables, through: :contacts
```

Since `contactable` is a polymorphic association, you can **optionally** specify the `contactable_type` like so:

```
has_many :contactables,
         through: :contacts,
         source: :contactable,
         source_type: "SomeClassName"
```

With that, you'll be able to do `user.contactables`

Comment: I added the User model and one of the models contacts is associated with to the question, to make it more clear.

Comment: Your following line of code is wrong: `has_many :contacts, through: :contactable` Remove the `through` option.

Answer (score 0):

did you add

```
has_many :contacts, :as => :contactable
```

to your User model?

In that case you can call `@user.contacts.all`

By the way.. you are mixing `comments` and `contacts` in your post...

Comment: Edited the question and tried your solution. It didn't throw an error but it counted 0, even after adding a new contact.

In my user model I have...

`has_many :contacts, through: :contactable`

And in the "Leadhooks" model, which is one of the contactables, I have...

`has_many :contacts, as: :contactable`

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your data-model. Humza's answer should get you further.